# c# Cannot open Database - Windows 10 Access 2016

Tags: c#, sql, ms-access

I make a c# form that read and write data to a Microsoft Access Database.
It worked when i had **windows 8.1** with **access 2013**.
Then i had install **windows 10** with *access 2016* and the same program return this error: **Cannot open database ''. It may not be a database that your application recognizes, or the file may be corrupt.**
The file isn't corrupt (i can open it with access).
The file is small then 2GB (500 KB).
How can I solve?

Comment: How are you connecting to your access file? Are you using an ODBC?

Comment: I use an oledb connection **using System.Data.OleDb;**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The password was too long, I solved it with a password shorter than 13 characters

Answer (score 0):

Try installing the [Access 2013 runtime](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=39358).

From Microsoft:

> The Microsoft Access 2013 Runtime enables you to distribute Access
>   2013 applications to users who do not have the full version of Access
>   2013 installed on their computers.

This should install the appropriate OLEDB drivers for you that you used to have on your old OS.

Comment: I try to install access 2013 runtime and access 2013 database engine but it doesn't work I try so with 2016 but it doesn't work